# at command: Garbled time

Tags: date, man, at

I am not able to run `at` command.

```
edward@ArchLinux:~$ at
Garbled time
```

what is wrong? Am I running it wrong?

Comment: The same error appears when I try to list all **at** current jobs. For it is better to use `atq` command or `at -l`. My answer comes from [using `at` without options in Windows systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/at). Sorry, if I misunderstood context or intention of the question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A timestamp (as recognized by `at`, see the fine manual) must be given:

```
bash-4.1$ echo echo hi | at teatime
job 5 at 2016-02-02 16:00
bash-4.1$
```