# At utility problem with echo "command" | at +[#][time-unit]

Tags: at

I desire to run a particular task 2 hours ahead from now.

In Bash 4.3 in Ubuntu 16.04 I executed:

```
tdm() {
    chmod -R a-x,a=rX,u+w "$drt"/phpmyadmin/
    echo "chmod -R 000 "$drt"/phpmyadmin/" | at +2h
}
tdm
```

I get:

> syntax error. Last token seen: +
>
> Garbled time

Maybe I should put current time in a variable `X` somehow and define **"at 2 hours from time `X`"?**

I didn't understand the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259399/at-command-garbled-time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the `at` manual on Ubuntu, the format of the time specification can be on the form

> `now + count time-units`, where the `time-units` can be `minutes`, `hours`, `days`, or `weeks`

This means that you should use

```
at now + 2 hours
```

to execute the command "in two hours time from now".